# Java - IllegalArgumentException when .buildConfiguration() is called

Tags: java, ini4j

So I set up a INI file for my IRC bot made with PircBotX and now a IllegalArgumentException is thrown at .buildConfiguration()

Code:

```
public Craftxbot() throws IOException{
    File inicheck = new File("config.ini");
    if(!inicheck.exists()){
        System.out.println("Configuration file not found, Making one.");
        inicheck.createNewFile();
        Wini ini = new Wini(new File("config.ini"));
        ini.add("Config");
        System.out.print("Nickname: ");
        ini.put("Config", "nick", input.next());
        System.out.print("Server Hostname: ");
        ini.put("Config", "serverHostname", input.next());
        System.out.print("Server Port: ");
        ini.put("Config", "serverPort", input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Default Channel: ");
        ini.put("Config", "defaultChannel", input.next());
        System.out.flush();
    }
    Wini ini = new Wini(new File("config.ini"));
    System.out.print("Nickserv Password: ");
    System.out.flush();
    String nickpass = input.next();
    Configuration<PircBotX> alpha = new Configuration.Builder<PircBotX>()
            .setName(ini.get("Config", "nick"))
            .setLogin("Craftxbot-Dev")
            .setNickservPassword(nickpass)
            .setAutoNickChange(true)
            .setServerHostname(ini.get("Config", "serverHostname"))
            .setServerPort(ini.get("Config", "serverPort", int.class))
            .addAutoJoinChannel(ini.get("Config", "defaultChannel"))
            .addListener(new Commands())
            .addListener(new EventHandler())
            .addListener(new PrivMsg())
            .buildConfiguration();
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify name
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:93)
at org.pircbotx.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:128)
at org.pircbotx.Configuration$Builder.buildConfiguration(Configuration.java:589)
at tk.craftxbox.bot.Craftxbot.<init>(Craftxbot.java:61)
at tk.craftxbox.bot.Craftxbot.main(Craftxbot.java:27)
```

Before adding the INI file it worked fine and as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your ini.get calls are returning null. One reason for this is that you never `ini.store()` after writing all your values. If you look at the example here: http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/OneMinuteTutorial.java.html you must call `store()` after writing values.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that in the tutorial.